# VSCode "Open Editors" panel not showing

Tags: visual-studio-code, missing-features

I don't know what I have done but I cannot see the "Open Editors" panel in the Explorer view

[image: Image of Open Editors missing]

I note also that clicking on the three dots (Views and More Actions...) to the right of the word Explorer at the top of the explorer panel the word Folders is greyed out

[image: Image of Folders greyed out]

Can anyone point me to the setting I need to change in order to rectify this situation?

Comment: What is your setting `Editor > Open Editors: Visible` set to?

Comment: It is set to 9. 

I did discover that setting it to 0 (zero) suppresses the the Open Editors panel in researching this problem. I did not discover anything else that affects its visibility, hence the question :-)

Comment: related and possibly a dup of https://stackoverflow.com/q/76144000/11107541

Answer (score 11):

Just in case anyone else has the same problem here is how I resolved my issue. I won't bore you with how I discovered the solution.
Right-click in the activity bar, this will bring up a context menu with the entry for Open Editors listed but not marked with a tick
[Activity bar context menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7RkuP.png).

Clicking on "Open Editors" in this context menu brings up a new icon in the activity bar that looks like an open book
[Open Editor icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G6VnV.png)

Right-clicking on this new icon reveals another context menu that includes the option to reset the location of the Open Editors panel.
[Open Editor context menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jp3eH.png)

Selecting this option resolves the problem.

How I got into the problem in the first place is still difficult to ascertain. With the activity bar in its default configuration I must have dragged the "Open Editors" header to somewhere on the activity bar, that clearly removes it from the Explorer side bar but how I inadvertently right clicked this new icon and selected "Hide 'Open  Editors'" without realising remains a mystery.

Comment: this one is correct answer, all other solutions did not worked

Comment: i think it happens when you (accidentally) drag the open editors or the explorer pane around

Answer (score 8):

Go to view and click on Open View and the on Open Editors.

[image]

3 dots on extreme right hand side has an option - keep editors open --> set it to default view. Once done the open editor will be be visible on the left.

[image]

This is considering you have default vs code layout...
I am currently using version: 1.68.1

Answer (score 2):

In VS Code, go to `Settings` and in the search box, type `explorer.openEditors.visible`. Set the value in the dialogue box to any number greater than `0` and you are good to go. Refer to the image below.

[image: Open Editors in VS Code]

Answer (score 2):

I am using VSCode Version 1.84.2 and here is what worked for me. Open up the Explorer side panel, click on the hamburger menu and make sure "Open Editors" is selected.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

VS Code main menu bar: "View" --> "Open View..." --> (scroll down) "Open Editors"

[vscode 1.77 on Mac]

Answer (score 0):

I had to go View -- menu to make the Open Editors section visible.

Answer (score 0):

VS Code main menu bar: "View" --> "Open View..." --> (scroll down) "Open Editors"

Worked for me in 1.87

What a mess changing the location of the setting so much.