# How can I find and restore a missing View, View subsection, or Panel in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

My desired behavior for the Explorer View in VS Code is that, when I open a folder, all of the files in the folder display in it. Currently, it only shows "Open editors" (which isn't quite what I want), "Outline", and "Timeline". When I create a workspace for a folder, however, the files in these folders preview (this is the behavior I want, without having to create a workspace!)

Here's what I'd like it to look like: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GKjoZ.png)

Comment: I'm a bit confused. a screenshot of what you're currently seeing might help. when you click the three-dot menu in the Explorer View, is the "Folders" item checked? If not, the answer is to click the "Folders" item so that it is checked. Actually, I don't even have an option to uncheck it... so now I'm _really_ confused. What files aren't you seeing? This might have to do with the `files.exclude` setting.

Comment: Are you saying you don't see an `Explorer` view at all?  If so, using the main menu: `View/Open View...` and choose Explorer.

Comment: @Mark it seems them can, since they say "_Currently in my explore tab is only Open editors (which isn't quite what I want), Outline, and Timeline._"

Comment: @user You can drag the Folders viewlet out of the Explorer view, and so be left with only the other viewlets he mentioned.  So what I should have asked is can he see the `Folders` viewlet in the Explorer view.

Comment: I'm not seeing the `Folders` viewlet in my `Explorer` view - how would I add this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll write talking about your specific case with the Folders subview of the Explorer view, but the steps should apply in general to any View, subview or Panel.

You might have accidentally hidden it, in which case you can unhide it by right clicking in the activity bar and then clicking its entry in the context menu to give it a checkmark there again indicating that you want it to not be hidden.

This might have been caused by moving (drag and drop) the subview/viewlet to some other are of the workbench. I'll give instructions for the Folders subview of the Explorer View, but these instructions can generalize to any subview of a View.

There's the "Secondary Side Bar" (also called "Auxillary Bar"), which you can toggle by using the `View: Toggle Secondary Side Bar Visibility` command in the command palette (bound by default to <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> on Windows and Linux- not sure what for macOS). Check if you moved it there, and if you did, Click and drag the "Folders" icon ([image]/[image]) at the top left of it back to the Explorer View.

Check also the Panel area (usually docked to the bottom of the screen), which you can toggle with the `View: Toggle Panel Visibility` in the command palette (bound by default to <kbd>ctrl/cmd</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd>). Check the tab strip in the title bar there to see if there's one that says "Folders". If it's there, drag and drop it back into the Explorer View.

If neither of those work, you can take the "nuclear option" and reset all your Views and Panels to their default positions using the `View: Reset View Locations` command in the command palette.