# VS code testing sidebar not there

Tags: visual-studio-code

[Right clicking does not provide any options for testing sidebar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKiu0.png)

Using React and vitest, created a `basic.test.jsx` file and restarted VS code a few times. No sidebar in sight. The gutter for testing is enabled in the user settings

Comment: can you check if [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76168136/11107541) helps? I get a feeling you moved it to somewhere else.

Comment: Hi @user, tried all those steps to no avail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to fix this by first doing `ctrl+shift+p` then `Add folder to workspace`. My react app was nested in a sub-folder and VS code couldn't find anything to test (I'm using vitest), once I did that the test explorer appeared

Answer (score 0):

The images below show how to add the test explorer icon on the VS Code sidebar.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks Jean-Pierre, my issue was I had my app in a sub-folder :)