# VS Code - In Ctrl+J menu i don't have a Terminal tab, how to add it?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm kinda new in IT industry, I'm currently learning, watching courses online, and I see that everybody uses the Terminal in **VS code** in the Ctrl + J menu (highlighted with green in the print screen, I don't know its name), but I don't have it there. Atm I open it manually from `View Tab > Terminal` or by shortcut < Ctrl + ` > (highlighted with red in the print screen) and it gets opened on the right side, which is annoying.

[image]

I right-clicked on the menu, maybe is unchecked, but is not there.
[image]

Thank you in advance,

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I find and restore a missing View, View subsection, or Panel in VS Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76144000/how-can-i-find-and-restore-a-missing-view-or-view-subsection-in-vs-code) you moved your Terminal Panel to the secondary sidebar. Just drag it back.

Comment: @starball, the link that you gave me doesn't help, but it seems yeah, i just moved the Terminal Panel to the secondary bar. Was that easy, to drag it back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show/hide Terminal you should use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>`</kbd> shortcut

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>J</kbd> is `> View: Toggle Panel Visibility`, and while it can be used for the same you don't have to.

To reset Terminal position back to the Panel, drag its tab into panel tabs, run `> View: Reset View Location` in <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> panel, or reset its position from the context menu [image]

Comment: Thanks! It worked! As a small precision to others, you have to right-click exactly on the small terminal icon (that play icon) to see Dimava's printscreen options, NOT on the secondary side bar.